# How to access Pdf-Viewer with Python Selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, pdf-viewer

Selenium: 3.141 | Chromedriver: 94.0.4606 | Python 3.7

Is there a way to use Selenium and access a pdf-viewer in order to mess with the zoom in/out as well as scrolling?

When I inspect the page, everything is kept under:
`<pdf-viewer id="viewer">`
but I can't seem to access anything. Do I need to switch to it like iframes? If so, does anyone know how that would look? I appreciate any advice!

This is the example site I've been using: https://www.equibase.com/premium/eqbPDFChartPlus.cfm?RACE=1&BorP=P&TID=ALB&CTRY=USA&DT=06/17/2002&DAY=D&STYLE=EQB